# How to get all documents per topic after merging in BERTopic?

Tags: topic-modeling

I am using BERTopic to generate topics on my dataset. After the initial topics are created, I used hierarchical clustering to identify some topics I considered too specific, so I created a list of lists of topics to merge and applied .merge_topics. Which works as intended. However, my topics list is not updated, since I only defined it when applying fit.transform to my dataset.

The answer should be something like in this thred [How to get all docoments per topic in bertopic modeling](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), but in my case I first have to access the new topics. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

docs = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all')['data']
topic_model = BERTopic()
topics, probabilities = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)

topics_to_merge = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
topic_model.merge_topics(docs, topics_to_merge)

df = pd.DataFrame({'topic': topics, 'document': docs})
```

Answer (score 2):

In the v0.13 release of BERTopic, there is now the option to extract document meta-data, including topics and probabilities, as follows:

```py
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

# Get your data
docs = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all',  remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))['data']

# Train your model
topic_model = BERTopic()
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)

# Create a dataframe with document metadata
df = topic_model.get_document_info(docs)
```

The output will look something like this:

```
>>> topic_model.get_document_info(docs)

Document                               Topic    Name                        Top_n_words                     Probability    ...
I am sure some bashers of Pens...       0       0_game_team_games_season    game - team - games...          0.200010       ...
My brother is in the market for...      -1     -1_can_your_will_any         can - your - will...            0.420668       ...
Finally you said what you dream...      -1     -1_can_your_will_any         can - your - will...            0.807259       ...
Think! It is the SCSI card doing...     49     49_windows_drive_dos_file    windows - drive - docs...       0.071746       ...
1) I have an old Jasmine drive...       49     49_windows_drive_dos_file    windows - drive - docs...       0.038983       ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the answer is very simple. Bertopic stores the topics that were generated for each document in topic_model.topics_.
So at the end, just create df using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Document": docs, "Topic": topic_model.topics_})
```